# How to create radio button in AS400 using DSPF record file and AS400

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

```
0001.90      A                                 13  3'Warehouse . . . . . .'  
0002.00      A            WAREHOUSE      2Y 0B 14  9SNGCHCFLD                
0002.10      A                                      CHOICE(1 '>W1')          
0002.20      A                                      CHOICE(2 '>W2')
```

This is my Source code. this does not display the output as a radio button. expected output screen like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pAnB.png). This code gives the output as[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMcjL.png). how to display the radio button using fixed format RPGLR and DSPF at RECORD type

Expected output Screen [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQL8t.png)

Comment: Did you try to display the radio button without the > character?
What client are you using to display the screen? I guess the character is interpreted by the client.

Comment: Not Sure about TN5250, but the documentation states nothing about enhanced display capabilities. Termina Emulation sounds like it is emulating a dumb 5250 terminal, which cannot diplay enhanced stuff.
I recommend using IBM I access client solutions, which should work.

Comment: Mocha does **not** support enhanced (pseudo-graphical) display.

Answer (score 3):

First off, when you compile the DSPF using CRTDSPF, make sure you specify
`ENHDSP(*YES)`

Second, what 5250 client are you using?  If not IBM's then contact your vendor to see if the client supports the 5250 GUI elements.

Remember 5250 is not a "dumb" terminal protocol.  The client does a considerable amount of processing.

Comment: hi Charles. Thank you for you answer. Please give some detailed answer. Am new in AS400.  Thanks

Comment: Seems pretty detailed to me, did you do the things he suggested? What client are you using?

Comment: I am using Mocha TN5250

Comment: @Charles ENHDSP(*YES) is default.

Comment: @PoC it may be the currently shipped default...doesn't mean it's the OP's default.